# How to set default value Combobox jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, combobox

I am want set default `value= ${theObject2.countryId}`

```
<select id="locationCountry" style="padding-left: 2em" >
<option value="">Country</option>
<c:forEach  items="${countrieDetail}" var="theObject" varStatus="theCount">
<option value="${theObject.countryId}" >${theObject.countryName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the default in the model attribute you are backing your form with?  Then Spring will just render the component with said value.

Comment: why theObject2 ? the "2" is a typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTML  selected Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp). Simply compare the Id and set it selected if matched.

Sample code:

```
<select id="locationCountry" style="padding-left: 2em">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <c:forEach items="${countrieDetail}" var="theObject">
        <option value="${theObject.countryId}" <c:if test="${theObject.countryId == theObject2.countryId }">selected</c:if>>
              ${theObject.countryName}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Look at this post as well [Keeping radio buttons selected with jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328294/keeping-radio-buttons-selected-with-jsp) where same logic is used to make it more clear.