# How to retrieve radio button value from database in checked state in jsp

Tags: jsp

How to retrieve radio button values with checked state in jsp ? while updating radio button from data base.

```
Male <input type="radio" name="R1" value="<%=rs.getString("gender")%>">
Female <input type="radio" name="R1" value="<%=rs.getString("gender")%>">
```

If in database its female it should be in checked state  female radio button
else male radio button 
its not checking the value for none

Comment: Possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779588/jsp-radio-button-values

Comment: i am getting the value of radio button  but unable to make it as checked.

Comment: just add `checked` to whichever you want to be checked by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) & [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead of Scriplet elements. For database access use JSTL [SQL Tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) or it's better to move the database code in the Servlet.

Try with the [CSS Input Radio checked Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp)

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:set var="gender" value="female"/>

Male <input type="radio" name="R1" 
            value="Male" <c:if test="${gender=='male'}">checked</c:if>>
Female <input type="radio" name="R1" 
            value="Female" <c:if test="${gender=='female'}">checked</c:if>>
```

Have a look at the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325782/how-to-set-default-value-combobox-jsp/24332010#24332010)

---

#### EDIT

> For check box values single value its show properly but when it multiple values showing nothing.

check the string using contains method.

sample code:

```
<c:set var="medium" value="Hindi Kannada" />

English
<input type="checkbox" name="C1"
    <c:if test="${medium.contains('English')}">checked</c:if>>
Kannada
<input type="checkbox" name="C1"
    <c:if test="${medium.contains('Kannada')}">checked</c:if>>
Hindi
<input type="checkbox" name="C1"
    <c:if test="${medium.contains('Kannada')}">checked</c:if>>
```

Comment: Ít's working fine. To test it just change the value of gender in the example.

Comment: Thank you very much . what i wanted is :). where can i learn jstl & EL scriplet elements ? Its Worked Perfectly

Comment: Sounds good. If the issue is resolved then don't forget to accept the answer by ticking green mark.

Comment: follow the links that I have shared you in the post for JSTL and EL.

Comment: in the same case For check box values single value its show properly but when it multiple values showing nothing .

Comment: You are talking about more than 3 radio buttons.

Comment: how are you getting multiple values from server? Is it in array?

Comment: print the value of medium `${medium}` and let me know what it contains.

Comment: when i print its showing     Kannada Hindi    both . because i have selected both while inserting into database.

Comment: "The function contains must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified". I got This Error

Comment: It's related to prefix that is using for JSTL tags as I declared `c` for core tag in the post.

Comment: It's time to post another question with your sample code.

Comment: Thank You very much for solving my Query +1

Answer (score -2):

update Radio Button in jsp:-
Code:-
 >Male

>Female