# Fetching checkbox value from database in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp

I am trying to check/uncheck my checkbox field in JSP,based on the values stored in my db.The code snippet for jsp is:

```
<div class="form-group t-margin-top-10">
                           <label for="defaultContact" class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                           <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                           <input type="checkbox" id="defaultContact${billingContactDto.billingContactId}"  name="defaultContact" /> Default Contact</div>
```

This is not showing default checked value (checked in this case).
billingContactDto is contacts object,
billingContactId is PK in billingContact object.
billingContact.defaultContact is a string in billingContact(not shown here)

The question is how to fetch values of checkbox from db.
Thanks in advance

Comment: there are two things involved in this post. 1) set default state of checkbox based on value stored in db 2) how to fetch values from db.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to check/uncheck my checkbox field in JSP,based on the values stored in my db

Try to use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) & [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead of Scriplet elements. For database access use JSTL [SQL Tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html).

It's better to move the database code in the Servlet.

steps to follow:

- Just fetch the record from database
- Store the result in an Object or List
- Set it in request attribute
- Redirect to JSP
- Access the value from request attribute in JSP using JSTL or EL

Try with the [HTML  checked Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:set var="gender" value="female"/>

Male <input type="checkbox" name="R1" 
            value="Male" <c:if test="${gender=='male'}">checked</c:if>>
Female <input type="checkbox" name="R1" 
            value="Female" <c:if test="${gender=='female'}">checked</c:if>>
```

Have a look at the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699681/how-to-retrieve-radio-button-value-from-database-in-checked-state-in-jsp/24700367#24700367)