# how to assign value dynamically to disabled attribute in spring mvc jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

I have to disable checkbox and its associated radio buttons

Under one checkbox there are many radio buttons so i want to disable the radio button based on some flag which is coming from database

when i assign dynamic flag to its disabled property it is not working

flag value is coming as false eventhough radio button is not disabled

```
<form:checkbox path="lstAuthFactor" value="${authLevelFactor.key}" label="${authLevelFactor.key}" disabled="true" />
                             <ul class="verticalRadios">
<form:radiobuttons path="authChainCodes[${seq1.index}].levelId" items="${authLevelFactor.value}" itemValue="levelId" itemLabel="levelDesc" element="li" disabled="levelActive"/>
```

here levelactive is boolean value but that is not working

Anybody please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after some time

```
<form:radiobuttons path="authChainCodes[${seq1.index}].levelId" items="${authLevelFactor.value}" itemValue="levelId" itemLabel="levelDesc" element="li"     disabled="${!authLevelFactor.value[seq1.index].levelActive}"/>
```

Here actually authLevelFactor.value is arraylist so i have assigned value from particular index

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) & [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to set the [HTML  input disabled property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<form:checkbox path="lstAuthFactor" value="${authLevelFactor.key}" 
          label="${authLevelFactor.key}" <c:if test="${flag}">disabled</c:if>/>
```

Have a look at the similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699681/how-to-retrieve-radio-button-value-from-database-in-checked-state-in-jsp/24700367#24700367) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789204/fetching-checkbox-value-from-database-in-spring-mvc/24789247#24789247)